# Reassociate Batch Files with Cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, windows-vista

I installed gvim on windows vista and got really excited to edit EVERYTHING with it. I associated .bat files with gvim, and now I can't get bat files to run... oops!! Could anyone explain how to reassociate .bat files with cmd.exe so that double clicking on them will make them just run?

**EDIT:**
I followed Jim's advice below by deleting the registry key. After restart bat files are still opening in my text editor. I double checked my registry, and the key had been recreated. I then discovered that the text editor was set in Control Panel > Default Programs > Associate a filetype. I changed bat files to open with the Cmd.exe, but Cmd.exe just opens without running the batch file. I'm guessing the problem is still in the registry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has the reg file downloads for all the default file extensions. Just download the bat one and run it, this should restore all the associations back to default.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

*Note: Although it says it is only for Win7 it should be fine for vista as well.*

Default_BAT.reg copy in case link dies:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; http://www.sevenforums.com
; Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
@="Windows Batch File"
"EditFlags"=hex:30,04,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,61,00,63,00,70,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,36,00,30,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,36,\
  00,38,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,00,6d,00,\
  64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,43,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,\
  00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.bat]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, Bali C

Comment: I have the same problem as GitNinja, but with a different text editor. I normally would prefer an explanation of the steps over a link to another site, but I reviewed the reg file at sevenforums.com and realized it would require a long explanation of the registry's structure to do that. I looked through my own registry for differences, then ran it. It worked perfectly for me on Win8.1Pro to solve the problem.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/53950/103551), only the last line is needed.

Comment: +1, this actually solves the problem unlike the common suggestion of just changing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.BAT\UserChoice

Comment: I wish more people would think ahead like you did about "if the link dies". I find so many answers contain links that are dead, and it is such a pain find the new link (if you are lucky and it still exists somewhere).

Answer (score 4):

Using regedit.exe, look for the key

```
.bat
```

under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

and delete it.

EDIT:
Also, this

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/fc2ca91d-5509-4c9b-92a5-5af19375e361

No longer have a problem with this myself but looked up the above anyway :) !

Comment: Thanks, Jim! I found this key, but it's still opening in my text editor. Maybe I just need a restart.

Comment: Still not working. I've edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

Merging a `.reg` file or [editing the registry manually](https://superuser.com/a/53950/103551) is the most reliable option, but perhaps you could simply run [`assoc .bat=`](https://superuser.com/a/569486/103551) from an admin command prompt.

If neither works, perhaps Windows is hiding file extensions from you and it's actually a `.bat.txt` file. Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" in File Explorer Options (formerly known as Folder Options) and rename the file.

Comment: `assoc .bat=` worked perfectly for me (on Windows 10). Thank you.